# Apple Push Notification: Device registered, but not receiving notification

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I have an ios app that uses IBM Bluemix MobileFirst Push notification. In the Bluemix console, I can see my device is registered. But when I sent notification from the console, I didn't see it on the device.
I have followed [apple tech note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html) and installed ersistentConnectionLogging.mobileconfig. The log files related to apsd is at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Up86Av5djnb0VDUEQ4STFWSzA/view?usp=sharing. 
the mobile is connected via cellular data.
Can you please help me to look at the log and see what is wrong?

Comment: Is your application running in the background when the notification was sent? Otherwise you will not see the notification.  If the application is in the foreground you can write some code to handle the notification in the didReceiveRemoteNotification function of your app delegate. Also please check to make sure you are using the correct APNS enabled certificate on Bluemix and that it is not expired.

Comment: All yes to your questions. Josh. I used the IBM DST to get bundle id and the cert. Used IBM build envoy to generate the ipa file and installed it on the device. I think the device is registered, because I see it from the Bluemix console. I am asking DST to get the deployment profile, so I can debug the deployed app on the device. But down the line, seems that there is problem with connection to the Apple gateway, I think I'll need to get the server side log, but there isn't a way for me to do that?

Comment: You can get the server side bluemix logs from your application either via the dashboard of your application in Files and Logs section or by using the cloud foundry CLI. Such as cf logs <App_Name> --recent. It would really help to see where the issue is happening. Might also be helpful to include the client side logs from xcode so we can investigate further when the server side logs are added.

Comment: Hi Josh, the server side log from the Bluemix console has nothing about push. And the deployed app is built by Build Envoy that I don't have the correct provisioning in my Xcode, so I can debug it in Xcode. I have built the bluelist sample app using my app bundle id in Build Envoy and it doesn't register itself. Could be a hiccup in Bluemix today?

Comment: Everything is running as expected in regards to Push and I was just able to test a sample application I have. I would assume your issue lies in either the APNs certificate or the provisioning profile. Please check to make sure you are using the correct ones for your environment. Also if you are unable to register the device you will not be able to send a push notification to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Josh for your great help to find out that my Bluemix app is in the sand box while my provisioning is for the production env.

How to move to the production mode, see https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpushrestapidocs/#!/applications/put_apps_applicationId_settings